# android return to grandparent activity

Tags: stack, android-activity

My main activity named "A" creates activity "B" by the use of

```
startActivity(intent);
```

And then "B" creates "C" in the same manner. I can go back either from "B" to "A" or from "C" to "B" using

```
finish();
```

method.

How do I go from "C" directly to "A"?

Answer (score 1):

Pass Intent from C to activity A:
Intent cIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),A.class);
startActivity(cIntent);

Comment: this brings me to "B", not to "A" activity unexpectedly (for me at least).

Comment: Please ignore my previuos comment. It was a result of typo in code. Anyway, I ended up with onActivityResult(...) callback in activity "B" and setResult() in activity "C".